# How can I know if the message has been sent by Tcp Socket in C# without client reply?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

How can I know if the message has been sent by Tcp Socket in C# without client reply?

Comment: Btw TCP is a stream-oriented transport. It doesn't deal with messages, just a stream of bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you send bytes using the `Send` method of a TCP Socket, TCP ensures that all bytes are delivered to the recipient. If the bytes cannot be delivered, the `Send` method will throw an exception.

Note, however, that a Socket may buffer some bytes before sending them, so even if TCP guarantees the delivery of the bytes, they might have not been sent yet when the `Send` method returns.

Also note that a program cannot determine if a TCP connection is broken if it only ever calls the `Receive` method. You have to send some data from time to time in order to check if the TCP connection is still working.

Comment: Thanks to sender side buffering this is not always true. Possible for a send to be buffered, and the the connection to fail.